# Radio button checked attribute not updating on user action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I am trying to monitor the change on a radio group.

I am  using topcoat with the following HTML :

```
<ul class="topcoat-list">
    <li class="topcoat-list__item">
       <label class="topcoat-radio-button__label">
            <input type="radio" name="topcoat" value="1" checked="checked">
            <div class="topcoat-radio-button"></div>
            Test1
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="topcoat-list__item">
        <label class="topcoat-radio-button__label">
            <input type="radio" name="topcoat" value="2">
            <div class="topcoat-radio-button"></div>
            Test2
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="topcoat-list__item">
        <label class="topcoat-radio-button__label">
            <input type="radio" name="topcoat" value="3">
            <div class="topcoat-radio-button"></div>
            Test3
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For a reason I don't quite get, the `checked` attribute does not get updated when the use selects another radio button...

I would like to be able to monitor the change with javascript, but right now, I can't get the value of the radio group...

```
$('input[name=topcoat]').change(function(){ changed() });

function changed() {
  id = $('input[name=topcoat]').val();
  alert(id);
}
```

Comment: when you select a checkbox, it is a property that gets updated not the attribute

Comment: you can get the selected item using `$('input[name="topcoat"]:checked').val()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, your comment solved my problem. I marked the answer down as accepted (I don't know which one of you was first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way and i hope it will solve your problem :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$('input[name="topcoat"]').change(function(){ changed() });

function changed() {
  id = $('input[name="topcoat"]:checked').val();
  alert(id);
}

});

</script>
```